# where do developers typically place xml files?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

In windows forms app, where do developers typically place files such as `XML` data source files with **.xml** extension?

Typically i place images in teh resources directory, likewise where do these .xml files go?

Im using VS 2010

Comment: Resources directory is fine

Comment: I would prefer them to be in My AppData Folder

Comment: In case your application will or can modify such XML data, it should be placed within directories where write access is granted. Is your application installed for the current user on `%appdata%\YourProgram`, the XML data should be in the same location. Is your application installed for all users on `%programfiles%\YourProgram` or `%programfiles(x86)%\YourProgram` the XML data should be in `%allusersprofile%\YourProgram`.

Comment: If your XML data will not be modified by the user at all, put them besides your program, where your program gets installed. In this case you can interpret the XML data as hard component of the program itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to prefer `Documents\MyApplication` if the file is user specific and file can have read and write access.

If the file is for only read purpose and it is not windows user specific then i would prefer to place that file in `Application StartupFolder`.

Comment: its for read purpose!

Comment: How do i place a find in teh startup folder?

Comment: yeah than there is no problem in to place that file in Application Folder. `Application.StartupPath` will retrieve the folder path where your application has installed

Comment: i want to drag this further, in General apps have so many types of files .xml is one of them, is it possible tell what type files goes in where abouts in a win forms app

Comment: The application hasn't writing rights on `Application.StartupPath` if the application is installed in `Program Files`.

Comment: the xml files im talking about mainly holds country names

Comment: Personally, I would avoid to use the `MyDocuments`, as it was desired the user uses it for it's documents. Many software does this, unfortunately.

Comment: Exactly @PatrickHofman that's why i am suggesting use Application Startup path when the file is for only read purpose.

Comment: @Shell: Just wanted to put it there for OP to understand. Keeps him from asking that question tomorrow :)

Comment: So the best place to install teh app's files are in teh app's own folder!

Comment: @AndrewMC you cannot tell it best. it depends upon your requirement.

Comment: So same applies for the .xsd files and all the other settings files that shown on "Add" --> "Add New Items" dialogbox?

Comment: yes but, be sure that file is not being updated during the application life time otherwise application throws the exception if the application is installed in %ProgramFile% folder. especially in Windows 7 and Windows 8.